# \ref overlapping following text

Tags: cross-referencing, texlive

I am looking to reference a section heading in my work but when I use `\ref{label}` the section number overlaps the following word. I am using the `ifmbe` document class. (`textcomp` package is being used in case that matters)

```
...Section \ref{sec:relatedWork} outlines...
\section{Related Work}\label{sec:relatedWork}
```

EDIT:

I should also point out that this problem does not occur when use `\ref` with figures. The section headings are using Roman Numerals whereas the figures are using Arabic Numerals.

Comment: Can you give a pointer to the `ifmbe` class? It's not on CTAN as far as I can see.

Comment: This should be the class download
http://ency15.mit.bme.hu/LaTeX_Template_for_IFMBE_Proceedings.zip

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitions given of `\thesection` and `\thesubsection` are completely wrong.

You get the same result, without the problem in `\ref` by doing

```
\documentclass[nouppercase]{ifmbe}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname.\ }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Section \ref{sec:relatedWork} outlines...

\section{Related Work}\label{sec:relatedWork}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the period after the section number in `\ref`, do

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.}
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\csname the#1\endcsname\ }
\makeatother
```

Comment: Good, you have already dug into the internals, +1. Since the subsection number is only showing itself and is reset at each section, `\renewcommand*{\p@subsection}{\thesection.}` includes the section number in the references.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I wouldn't make incompatible changes: they don't provide this. On the other hand, having the period after the section number in a cross reference is a stylistic decision (and is wrong, in my opinion).

Comment: I wouldn't use the mix of `\Roman` and `\Alph` in the first place. Is `I` a section or subsection number? I agree with you on the wrong dot after the section number. I consider this as bug of the class as the wrong `\hspace` command. The period belongs rather to `\@seccntformat`.

Answer (score 3):

The cause is a faulty definition of `\thesection` and `\thesubsection`, which include negative space at the end of the number:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}.\hspace{-3mm}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\Alph{subsection}.\hspace{-2mm}}
```

The following workaround uses `\secref`, which removes the space locally:

```
\documentclass{ifmbe}
\newcommand*{\secref}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand*{\hspace}[1]{}%
    \ref{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
\begin{document}
Section \secref{sec:relatedWork} outlines
\section{Related Work}\label{sec:relatedWork}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

An alternative workaround uses `\seclabel` and `\subseclabel` instead of `\label` for `\section` and `\subsection`. Then the counter appearance can easily be defined without a dot and the reference for a `\subsection` can include the section number:

```
\documentclass{ifmbe}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\seclabel}[1]{%
  \@bsphack  
  \begingroup
    \edef\@currentlabel{\Roman{section}}%
    \label{#1}%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
\newcommand*{\subseclabel}[1]{%
  \@bsphack  
  \begingroup
    \edef\@currentlabel{\Roman{section}.\Alph{subsection}}%
    \label{#1}%
  \endgroup
  \@esphack
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Section \ref{sec:relatedWork} and \ref{sec:sub} outlines
\section{Related Work}\seclabel{sec:relatedWork}
\subsection{Subsection}\subseclabel{sec:sub}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]